# I have an idea/invention and look for a real investor/industry to take it to the next level?

Tags: prototyping, production

I checked many online resources/websites and all of them asked me to pay thousands of dollars to make it real! I couldn't find any one that says you don't have to pay and we will take it from here once we hear about your invention and decide that we like it!!!
Do you know/heard of any reliable willing investors or industries that welcome new inventions or ideas within the electronics field?
Thanks

Comment: You do not have to pay, just write your idea here on the SE.EE website, and then we will decide if we like it!

Comment: Look for venture capital companies. Prepare a short presentation and be ready to be rejected.

Comment: The burden of proof is yours to prove a business plan and design reliability are accurate.  Do you have any ideas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's because ideas are ten a pennny, and real engineering is extremely expensive once you have to pay professional engineers and contract manufacturers. If you can, produce a working prototype of your invention, then look for a venture capital company. You also need a [NDA form](https://www.entrepreneur.com/article/31812) for them to sign, plus a detailed business case for the invention. Just getting the paperwork together is probably going to take you a few weeks of effort.

Comment: Well, you can fool (well, *convince*)  some investors with nice presentations as well, without a prototype. I saw this before..

Comment: I've secured venture capital before and you wrote an excellent summary. +1 for that. Probably the only thing I'd add is that investors resist if they don't see substantial evidence that you are even more-invested, already. For example, selling your valuables and home and car, building something they can see, gives them "something tangible to see" but more importantly also shows them that you already "jumped off the cliff," so to speak. That goes a long way in convincing them that you believe in your idea and aren't just selling a pipe dream. They want to see some spilled blood of yours.

Comment: @jonk Some say the entrepreneur should not invest a penny from their own  pocket. I saw startups growing on the hype only. Just have the words "medical device" or "IoT"  (or whatever is on the "hottest" at the moment) in your presentation and investors will go like "shut up and take my money". But surely you need a skill not taught in engineering schools for that.

Comment: @EugeneSh. I can't argue with "some say," since they aren't here to defend themselves. I also can't tell you about your experiences. But I can tell you that my experiences are mine. I gave my advice to a hopeful engineer, some years back, to help him understand why he was failing to get any investment for the prior two years. He had a very good idea (I thought.) He then took my advice. Next thing I knew he was opening up just a block away from my business and had secured investment through a firm I'd recommended to him. That's my experience. But different places will have their own, I'm sure.